# Question about the Image of a compact transformation of a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compactness, compact-operators

$T$ is a compact operator on a Hilbert space. Show that $\operatorname{im}(T)$ does not contain a closed infinite dimensional subspace.

Here is my attempt at the problem:
Suppose that $\operatorname{im}(T)$ had a closed infinite dimensional subspace.  Then let $\{e_n\}$ be its orthonormal basis.  since $||e_n-e_m||=2$ for all $n,m$, it follows that the infinite sequence ${e_n}$ does not have a convergent subsequence. which would mean that a closed subset of a compact set is not compact.

Comment: Doesn't work. Where did you use the fact that $T$ is compact here?

Comment: If it was compact then shouldn't the en's have a convergent subsequence?

Comment: Only if they are the image of a bounded sequence. A compact operator maps *bounded* sets into precompact sets. It does NOT map everything into precompact sets.

Comment: Okay I see the issue.  Is it possible to salvage my method or is it a completely lost cause?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $im(T)$ is closed and infinite-dimensional. Consider the quotient space $\hat T=X/\ker T$. Then the operator
$$
\hat T:\hat X\to im(T), \ \hat T(\hat x)= Tx, \ x\in \hat x
$$
is bounded and continuous. Moreover, since $\ker T$ is closed, $\hat X$ is a Banach space. Then $\hat T$ is a linear, continuous, and bijective mapping, thus
it has a continuous inverse. However, since $T$ is compact, $\hat T$ is compact as well. Contradiction.